# Finding length of side in triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

**Problem**

In the following triangle, show that the length $\text{CD} = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}a$.

[image]

**My solution**

Using the Pythagorean Theorem on a 30-60-90 triangle, we get

$$CD = \sqrt{a^2 - \frac{a^2}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}a$$

However, it was pointed out to me that this property of 30-60-90 triangles is outside the curriculum.

**Question**

Can someone outline or show me another solution to this problem? Apparently, I used the "wrong" one.

Comment: How can triangles $\;30-60-90\;$ be outside **any** geometry curriculum??

Comment: It's ridiculous. It's such a fundamental rule, which apparently I must have picked up elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, it is absolutely ridiculous, as this value of cosine follows from Pythagoras's theorem. If your solution is considered wrong, the curriculum is all wrong in my opinion. However, if the curriculum simply requires memorization of the main values of sines and cosines, it's kinda okay then.  Just an opinion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of cosine function, 
$$
CD = a\cos30^\circ = {\sqrt3\over2}a
$$
from the right triangle BCD. (In this triangle, $a$ is hypotenuse, and $CD$ is the leg adjacent to the $30^\circ$ angle.)

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks!

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer as it is correct, yet I'm afraid trigonometry might be off the record if $\;30-60-90\;$ triangles aren't in the curriculum...

Comment: How could we get $\cos 30^0$ without $ 30-60-90$ triangle?

Comment: @Narasimham You are right; logically we couldn't get $\cos30^\circ=\sqrt3/2$ without studying the 30-60-90 triangle first. However, it looks like we shouldn't expect too much logic from (some) modern curriculums...

Answer (score 0):

As a student you have a moral obligation to obliterate the confines of your curriculum:

[image]

This equilateral triangle is a nice 'cheat sheet' in case you forget the values of $\sin 60^\circ,\sin 30^\circ$ and the cosine of those angles.  By drawing an equilateral triangle with side lengths $2$, and bisecting it, all the remaining information follows.